# Convert TIMESTAMP_TZ to TIMESTAMP_NTZ in Snowflake SELECT

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a tables in Snowflake that have fields of both `TIMESTAMP_TZ` and `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` types.

I would like to do a `SELECT * FROM <table>` such that all `TIMESTAMP_TZ` fields are read as `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` (using `TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ()` function).

How do I implement such a query?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error when you use TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ?

```
WITH sample_data AS (
SELECT '2020-11-22 20:00'::timestamp_tz A)
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(A) FROM sample_data;
```

Comment: No errors there. But I need to do a SELECT *, since I do not know which fields need to be convert to TIMESTAMP_NTZ. I just to convert any field that is TIMESTAMP_TZ to TIMESTAMP_NTZ.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the matter of how it is displayed, you could do:

```
alter session set TIMESTAMP_TZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'; 
select * from table_name;
```